# how to change raspberry pi ip in flask web service

Tags: python, networking, flask, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi 3b+ and i'm showing ip camera stream using the Opencv in python.
My default ip in rasppberry is 169.254.210.x range and I have to put the camera in the same range.
How can i change my raspberry ip?
Suppose if I run the program on a web service such as a flask, can i change the raspberry pi server ip every time?

Answer (score 0):

You can statically change your ip of raspberry pi by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`
Try editing a line of the file which contains `address`.

Comment: Tnx how i can this change in flask web service ?

Comment: You can't change in flask web service. You should access raspberry-pi via ssh or directly.